# How to turn on Activity Metrics?

Tags: android-activity, salesforce, metrics

I am struggeling activating the Einstein Activity Metrics as described in the Salesforce docs:
https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.aac_activity_metrics_enable.htm&type=5

I activated "Einstein Activity Capture" and I have access to the "Activities Dashboard".
In "Einstein Activity Capture --> Settings" I do not have the option to activate the Activity Metrics. I think this is related to the following note:

> If you have at least one licensed Einstein Activity Capture user, all Salesforce users in your company can use the Activity Metrics fields. If you have only Standard Einstein Activity Capture users, you can’t use Activity Metrics.

Where do I get the "Einstein Activity Capture Licence" from? For the moment in permission sets I only have "Standard Einstein Activity Capture".
I am on an  Enterprise Edition.

Thanks for any help.

Pascal

Answer (score 0):

I've just solved this problem in one of the orgs I manage. It was a Professional edition org so the answer may vary slight for an Enterprise Org.

The "Standard Einstein Activity Capture" licenses you are seeing in your org are free licenses that enable activity capture for all your users (i.e. you can assign permissions to your users from the Einstein setup and follow through with the outlook/gmail setup to start syncing emails and calendar events.) These licenses don't give access to the Activity Metrics you are looking for. You will need an additional license for that.

Ask your AE for a Salesforce Einstein License. 1 license for the administrator is all you need to access the fields (e.g. create formula fields on objects that use these metrics)
Alternatively you can purchase 1 Inbox license which will also unlock this feature.

In my case I went with an Inbox license. Once activated, in the Einstein Activity Capture Settings, the "Activity Metrics" option was enabled and I was able to use the fields.